# Can constexpr recursion limit be configured for clang or gcc?

Tags: gcc, clang, constexpr, compiler-options

Can constexpr compile-time recursion limit be configured through command line options for clang or gcc? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I exceed the limit with gcc, I get this error message:

```
error: constexpr evaluation depth exceeds maximum of 512 (use -fconstexpr-depth= to increase the maximum)
```

and according to the [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#cmdoption-fconstexpr-depth), clang understands the same option.